# Test spring classes in separate gradle subproject

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, spring-boot

My project is separated into several gradle subprojects (modules). I have a module which contains several spring components/beans. I want to test these beans using junit, mockito and springboottest with features like autowired and mockbean. I am using

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
```

annotations, but when I try to run a test I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

This happens because there is no main class (@SpringBootApplication) in this module.

One can avoid this by creating a mock main class like

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TestApp {
}
```

Is there a way to make it work without creating a mock main class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run test in sub-module you need to define some configuration class. It can be `@Configuration` with `@ComponentScan` located in `src/test/java` root package of sub-module, so that it wouldn't pollute your production code.

With such test configuration, just use `@SpringBootTest(classes=YourTestConfiguration.class)`.

Maybe you want to look at new annotation since Spring Boot 1.4.x called `@TestConfiguration`. That one is specifically tailored towards test only configs.

Comment: Looks like the same as creating mock main class (which can also be located in src/test/java).

Comment: Without some `@Configuration` (from which is `@SpringBootApplication` extended), you wouldn't be able to run any test with Spring Context